# Использование OpenCV в Service на ОС Android

Tags: android, service, opencv

Добрый день.

При разработки службы (Service) в ОС Android с использованием библиотеки OpenCV4Android, требуется обработать с использованием методов кадры (Frame) с камеры в background-режиме. 
Из всех советов, находил и про SurfaceView, и про создании отдельных служб, но так и не понял, как адаптировать это дело - не черта не понял.

И собственно вопросы:

1. Как обработать фреймы камеры в созданном Service?
2. Как адаптировать это всё под использование OpenCV4Android.

P.S. ответы находил на эти вопросы здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811303/android-opencv-process-camera-frames-in-a-service

Но не понял, как этим можно воспользоваться, если кто сможет объяснить - буду благодарен.

**UPDATE**
Разобрался в итоге, если у кого-то есть вопросы - пишите.
Достаточно интегрировать класс HardwareCamera из ссылки в вашу службу. При удалении некоторых неиспользуемых методов и редактировании кода вполне работает в службе и позволяет обрабатывать фреймы камеры, используя OpenCV.

P.S. Таким образом, мне удалось заставить обнаруживать лица на камере, используя несколько примеров из интернета.

Comment: я так не смог разобраться, как прикрутить этот класс HardwareCamera в мой сервис (
поделитесь, пожайлуста, как именно вы это сделали?

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из обновления вопроса:

Разобрался в итоге, если у кого-то есть вопросы - пишите. Достаточно интегрировать класс *HardwareCamera* из ссылки в вашу службу. При удалении некоторых неиспользуемых методов и редактировании кода вполне работает в службе и позволяет обрабатывать фреймы камеры, используя *OpenCV*.

P.S. Таким образом, мне удалось заставить обнаруживать лица на камере, используя несколько примеров из интернета.